# Using DesignData in WPF without including it into build

Tags: c#, wpf, design-data

I have some Design time view models bound to d:DataContext like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.Views.CallRecordView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModels.DesignTime"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:MyDesignViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
             mc:Ignorable="d vm">
```

I changed `Build Action` of every `ViewModel` from `Compile` to `DesignDataWithDesignTimeCreatableTypes`

and it's working on design time, but when I try to compile I get following errors:

```
Error   20519   The type or namespace name 'DesignTime' does not exist in the namespace 'MyProject.ViewModels' (are you missing an assembly reference?) ...\obj\Debug\Views\MyView.g.cs 13  35  MyProject
```

how can I prevent my sample data from being attached to an assembly? Or maybe this is not neccessary and the compiler wouldn't include those files into executable by default even on `Compile` setting?

// edit:

also - everything is working and compiling when I create an empty class into `DesignTime` namespace:

```
namespace MyProject.ViewModels.DesignTime {}
```

but can I do it without changing my namespace or providing an empty one for compile time?